# Trouble with vimrc

Tags: vimrc, indentation

So I've been using Vim at school with a vimrc that seemed to be well set up, and learn few extra commands like set nu or syntax on.

Right now I'm trying I'm using Vi on my computer, and was struck by how bad Vi default configuration was, and am trying to set my vimrc but it's hell as well:

```
1 filetype indent on
2 set tabstop=4
3 set backspace=indent,eol,start
4 syntax enable
5 set nu
```

The backspace is unpractical (not deleting letters as it should naturally), my vimrc is displaying an error message when I start it up. Are the function summoned in vimrc wrong? Thanks.

Edit: Yup, nope, this irrational backspace crap is driving me crazy. I can't get a regular backspace behavior (deletes previous character, period). Set backspace and filetype indent don't work.

Edit#2: So Vim backspace still won't behave humanly, I'm still trying to figure the f how to implement a normal backspace (which removes previous characters, period)

Comment: What error message do you get? Where is that `vimrc`?

Comment: Hi, I'm on OSX. I get: 

/usr/share/vim/vimrc" 5L, 86C
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/python.vim:
line   86:
E475: Invalid argument: pythonFunction
line   87:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   93:
E475: Invalid argument: pythonString

Also trying to figure out how StackExchange formatting works.

Comment: https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc

Comment: You have problems wit the syntax file for python in there.  Could you give us the lines in that file?  It might be that that match is not correctly written for Vim73

Comment: how to find that file?

Comment: The vimrc looks fine, are you sure vim loads the vimrc you edited? Can you try to comment out "syntax on" in your vimrc? If the error disappeared after you comment out that line, then it means there's some problem in python.vim as the error suggested. Also how did you install the vim? Did you modify any runtime files?

Answer (score 1):

2 suggestions:

1) Are you trying to use Vi or Vim? On most systems 'vi' is just a link to vim, but it may not be the case on your system. Your description of the backspace makes it sound a little like you may be using vi instead of vim.

2) If you don't like the default vim options, you could look into NeoVim (https://neovim.io/). I believe one of their objectives is to improve on what options are enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks, will look it up, but I'm trying to understand vi/vim/vimrc and how to properly set it up on any computer.